# Type annotations for Django models

Tags: python, django, type-annotation

I'm working on a Django project. Since this is a new project, I want to have it fully annotated with python 3.6+ type annotations. I'm trying to annotate models, but I struggle to find a good method for that.

Let's take the `IntegerField` as an example. I see two choices for annotating it:

```py
# number 1
int_field: int = models.IntegerField()

# number 2
int_field: models.IntegerField = models.IntegerField()
```

Number 1 fails in mypy:

```
Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "IntegerField[<nothing>, <nothing>]", variable has type "int")
```

Number 2 is OK for mypy, but IDE's as PyCharm are not able to resolve it and are often complaining about wrong types used.

Are there any best practices to correctly annotate the models, which will satisfy mypy and IDE's?

Comment: Since you seem to invest a lot of time into satisfying tools, you might be surprised to hear that what you do, is not what type annotation are **not** designed for: static typing.

Comment: Aren't you looking for something like [mypy-django](https://github.com/machinalis/mypy-django)?

Comment: Looks like mypy-django do not offer type annotations for models: https://github.com/machinalis/mypy-django-example/blob/master/polls/models.py#L8

Comment: @KlausD. - I'm not sure if I understand what you're saying, can you elaborate?

Comment: so even if you work this out for IntegerField(), what do you plan for a 50 char field? It's kind of nice to know that is sort of a string, but it's not really. I'm going to ask a naive question, but they already have types. You are trying to cast them to basic types, it seems to me.. what problem do you want to solve, exactly? It's quite a hard problem ... see how far Rust has got with it.

Comment: @Djent How about `int_field: Union[int, models.IntegerField] = models.IntegerField()`?

Comment: @Djent can you provide exact error from PyCharm?

Comment: @wowkin2 PyCharm just complains, eg. when a function takes int argument, and I'll use the field from a model. Then the function call is highlighted and PyCharm says `Expected 'int', got 'IntegerField'`.

Comment: @aaron: no, because that’s definitely wrong. The issue is that a Django model is a very different beast; the class contains fields, instances contain concrete values. The types *change with context*, instances don’t have an `IntegerField`, but if you use `Union` then all code accessing that field would have to account for the possibility.

Comment: @aaron: and besides, the `IntegerField()` field definition already gives us a type annotation; we know, from reading this model, that instances will have in `int_field` attribute with an integer value. Mypy just needs to be taught this same inference. Which is what django-stubs does. See the answer by bug.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Django models (and other components) are hard to annotate because there is a lot of magic behind them, good news is that a group of *cool developers* have already done the hard work for us.

[django-stubs](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs) provides a set of stubs and mypy plugins which provide static types and type inference for Django.

For instance, having the following model:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models

User = get_user_model()

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pubdate = models.DateTimeField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

mypy would complain saying:

```
demo$ mypy .
demo/models.py:9: error: Need type annotation for 'title'
demo/models.py:10: error: Need type annotation for 'pubdate'
demo/models.py:11: error: Need type annotation for 'author'
Found 3 errors in 1 file (checked 5 source files)
```

To fix it, it's enough to install the package

```
pip install django-stubs
```

and create a `setup.cfg` file with the following:

```
[mypy]
mypy_path = ./demo
plugins =
    mypy_django_plugin.main

strict_optional = True

[mypy.plugins.django-stubs]
django_settings_module = demo.settings
```

*(Don't forget to update `mypy_path` and `django_settings_module` to point to the directory of your settings module, according to how yours is named)*

Once this is done, mypy will be able to infer and check annotations for Django models (and other components).

```
demo$ mypy .
Success: no issues found in 5 source files
```

---

Here is an example of the usage in a small view:

```py
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
from django.http import HttpRequest, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

from demo.models import Post

def _get_posts() -> 'QuerySet[Post]':
    return Post.objects.all()

def posts(request: HttpRequest, template: str='posts.html') -> HttpResponse:
    return render(request, template, {'posts': _get_posts()})
```

Once again, mypy is happy with the provided annotations:

```
demo$ mypy .
Success: no issues found in 7 source files
```

---

On the same note, a package for Django Rest Framework is also available: [djangorestframework-stubs](https://github.com/typeddjango/djangorestframework-stubs).

Comment: I've actually found this, but I've used it wrong. Thank you for the detailed answer that helped me move forward.

Comment: Looks like the plugin tries to execute the Django project itself too, so it fails to run if, e.g.: it relies on a specific environment or alike.

Comment: Since the answer doesn't explicitly mention this, and it's part of the question, simply installing django-stubs in your project's python in PyCharm will fix PyCharm's complaints about your types, too. PyCharm's built-in Django support does handle types for most Django things properly, but fails horribly with fields being used as their values.

Comment: The `djangorestframework-stubs` link included is a fork.
Please, use the original repo.