# How to use T=TypeVar('T', bound=...) with Type[T] correctly?

Tags: python, django, django-models, mypy, python-typing

I have the following type-annotated Django code:

```
from typing import Optional, Type, TypeVar

from django.db import models

T = TypeVar('T', bound=models.Model)


def get_obj_or_none(model: Type[T], obj_id: int) -> Optional[T]:
    try:
        return model.objects.get(pk=obj_id)
    except model.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

The function expects a class derived from `django.db.models.Model` as the first parameter and an `int` id as the second parameter:

```
# obj is now the Person with id 123, or None if that didn't exist.
obj = get_obj_or_none(Person, 123)
```

But when I run mypy on the code, I get the error:

> ```
> error: "Type[T]" has no attribute "objects"
> error: "Type[T]" has no attribute "DoesNotExist"
> ```

But if change my code to this and run mypy again, I get no errors:

```
from typing import Optional, Type

from django.db import models


def get_obj_or_none(model: Type[models.Model], obj_id: int) -> Optional[models.Model]:
    try:
        return model.objects.get(pk=obj_id)
    except model.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

Why doesn't the first example work? I would really prefer to use it since the second example doesn't tie the return value in any way to the `model` parameter, so the function could be returning an instance, which is completely unrelated to the class given as the first parameter.

I'm using Python 3.8.1 with mypy 0.761.

---

**Edit**:

Here's a self contained example, which can be tested as is:

```
from typing import Dict, Optional, Type, TypeVar


class Model:
    objects: Dict[int, 'Model'] = {}


T = TypeVar('T', bound=Model)


def get_obj_or_none(model: Type[T], obj_id: int) -> Optional[T]:
    try:
        return model.objects[obj_id]
    except KeyError:
        return None
```

Running mypy on this gives (to my surprise) a completely different error:

> ```
> type_example.py:17: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Model", expected "Optional[T]")
> Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
> ```

Why does mypy behave differently on these two examples? Can I fix both of the cases somehow?

Comment: How are you type checking Django, btw? Via [django-stubs](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs) or something else? Your second example doesn't work because while `model` is generic, 'objects' isn't: a `Dict[int, Model]` could contain multiple distinct subclasses of Model. IDK how to fix though. If you had just T, you could make objects a property with a [generic self](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#generic-methods-and-generic-self). But for Type[T], you'd need to maybe mess with descriptors to hand-roll a "classproperty", or try a completely different approach...

Comment: @Michael0x2a I don't really fully understand that comment, you feel like expanding that to an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example works correctly after setting up [django-stubs](https://pypi.org/project/django-stubs/) for my project. Good instructions can be found from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59161962/9835872).

The last example gives correctly an error from mypy, since it's not allowed by Python. To quote from [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8352#issuecomment-581930544) I opened:

> The objects attribute can contain an instance of an arbitrary `Model` subclass, but the return type of `get_obj_or_none` contains a specific subtype `T` of `Model`. `Type[T]` has no effect in this example, since the type of the `objects` attribute is the same in subclasses (it doesn't use a "self" type). I don't think that there's a way to use a self type for a class variable.